# How do I remove/overrite the contents of a default menu on google add-on using Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-apps-marketplace

I'm building a Google Forms add-on and this is my `onOpen` function which opens a dialog.

But there are two default menus already present in the dialog that I haven't added manually.

1. Help
2. Install

[image: Add-on dialog box]

I have two questions:

1. How do I remove the Help and Install menus?
2. If I can't remove them, how do I use them? how do I access the menu and add content via code?

My onOpen function:

```
  FormApp.getUi()
      .createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('My addOn', 'dialog')
      .addItem('Help', 'showHelp')
      .addSeparator()
      .addToUi();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Install` and `Help` are added by Google. You can't remove or override them.

`Install` is shown when the add-on was enabled in the form but not yet installed by the active user.

`Help` shows the add-on description, the Learn more button set in the G Suite Marketplace SDK settings for the add-on, and may also show other buttons also based on the G Suite Marketplace SDK settings.

Other buttons that can be shown on the built-in Help dialog are

- Report an issue
- View in store

Resources

- [Publishing an editor add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove or modify those menu items just like you cannot modify any of the other Google menu items - they are built-in.

Comment: okay, I understand the part where I can't remove install. But is there any way to customize the help icon to set my application's context?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You can make an additional help menu entry, but it won't replace the in-built one.

Answer (score 2):

On reading a few documents, I realised that the `Install` button triggers this function:

```
/**
 * The event handler triggered when installing the add-on.
 * @param {Event} e The onInstall event.
 */
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}
```

I installed various add-ons and found that the `Help` button triggers a generic Help dialog box the content of which are displayed after the deployment of an add-on.
[image: sample help dialog box]

Comment: The onInstall function is also triggered when the user installs the add-on from Add-ons > Get add-ons